# How do I redirect traffic from a domain on other servers to content on mine?

Tags: node.js, url, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-route53

Here's the basic situation:

I have an application on AWS which needs to serve assets to and create 'share' links for content hosted on my AWS servers. I need to figure out a way to still use the URL/domain from another clients infrastructure, so it will essentially whitelabel our application as coming from their services. I was thinking of using Route53 and a CNAME, but things like the dynamic 'share' urls will create a huge problem for redirects. Does anybody have any ideas on how this could be accomplished?

Comment: What are "dynamic 'share' urls"...?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will have to set up your server at the "whitelabeling" location to have a web server that can call the other URLs and return their content.  Ie, you create a server that responds at whitelabel.com, which then calls myAWS.com and passes the result back to whoever called whitelabel.com.  You could make this flexible by allowing whatever the end destination URL needs to be to be passed in as a parameter (so, if you call whitelabel.com/foo, it will call myAWS.com/foo), though this has some security ramifications, and also requires a lot of knowledge by the consumer of exactly where things will reside.